# Fastest way to replace columns of values within a file from columns of another file using bash shell command?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to do a simple job by replacing certain column values within a file from columns from another value, for example, I want to replace two columns from file1, let's say 2nd and 3rd by values from file2. So the expected output will be something like: File3

File1:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

File2:

```
5 6
5 6
5 6
```

File3:

```
1 5 6 4
1 5 6 4
1 5 6 4
```

So my current solution is using awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;b[NR]=$2;next}{$2=a[FNR];$3=b[FNR]}1' File2 File1>File3
```

But I feel if I have a million lines, it could be too slow, since each time I have to scan through file 1 and file 2 line by line to restore or recall the arrays I created within awk.
Since File1 and File2 has similar length, I was wondering if I could do something like passing the values of File2 as a variable and replace it directly.
I attempted something like:

```
F2_col1=`awk '{print $1}' File2`
F2_col2=`awk '{print $2}' File2`
awk -v F2_col_v1=$F2_col1 -v F2_col_v2=$F2_col2 '{$2=F2_col_v1;$3=F2_col_v2;print }'File1 >File3
```

But it will raise an error saying cannot read file 5. Seems like awk trying to read values of File2 as an individual file? I am wondering how to do it correctly? Or is there any other faster way to do this. I am only concerned about computation time, so any suggestion is welcome (not limited to awk).

Comment: With your first awk you scan file 1 once, and then file 2 once. The array lookups are constant time (they are hashtables underneath) so all in all you're looking at linear time in the combined file sizes. That's the minimum in a general sense. Maybe some details can make it faster or slower, but I don't think anything will show any kind of dramatic improvement over your first awk.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Maybe I need to optimize other parts of my script.

Answer (score 3):

Since you specified that it does not have to strictly be `awk`, my suggestion would be to combine the files and only print the selected columns:

```
file1=$1
file2=$2

paste "${file1}" "${file2}" | awk '{print $1" "$5" "$6" "$4}' >file3.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `awk` variables are not quoted, e.g.

```
awk -v F2_col_v1="$F2_col1" -v F2_col_v2="$F2_col2" ...
```

and the first shell variable expands to `-v F2_col_v1=5 5 5`. But I don't know a way to combine those variables with `awk` that would make sense.

The common `cut` and `paste` approach would be

```
paste -d' ' <(cut -d' ' -f1 File1) file2 <(cut -d' ' -f4 File1) > File3
```

if the number of lines in both input files is the same.

You'll have to test both variants and stop the time. I wouldn't be suprised if `awk` is faster since `File1` is read twice.